# One quantum of energy

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, conservation-laws, atomic-physics

I came across a question that asked me to identify which transition within a hydrogen like atom will result in the emission of *one quantum of energy*. Exactly what is the definition of "one quantum of energy"? Does such a definition even exist?

Comment: Presumably it means a single photon. See the appropriate [selection rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_rule)

Comment: Oh, so in that case, won't all transitions within a hydrogen or hydrogen like atom result in the emission of one quantum of energy?

Comment: Oh no, I only just graduated high school. My level of study isn't that high. Thanks for the link anyway :)

Comment: High school level? Then I have no idea what they're asking for. Maybe someone else does?

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that **every** transition will result in the emission of one photon? Oh, no, but if it's a transition from say, 4 to 2, then there will be a total of 3 photons, yes? 4-2, 4-3, and 3-2. Huh. Does anybody else know the answer?!

Comment: I would hazard a guess it's a badly worded question, they **might** mean relative to other transitions from higher energy states, so relatively speaking, rather than an absolute value.

Comment: Unless there is more to the question that you haven't told us,  it's a very poor question.  I have never heard the phrase *one quantum of energy* used in this way; I don't know what it means.  If *photon* is meant, then every transition can emit one.  Even the so-called "forbidden" transitions do emit photons (via the quadrupole interaction).

Comment: @count_to_10: No no, this is all the information I have. The options are as follows: a. 4-2 b. 2-1 c. 3-1 d. 4-1 and according to the answer key, **all** the options are correct! This was a problem in something similar to the SAT(but much more advanced) conducted in India, called the IITJEE so there's close to zero chance that it's wrongly worded. Anyway, thanks for ur help. If anyone else knows, do say!

Comment: @garyp: So in the case that they meant the photon, **all** transitions emit one? Don't they emit more than one sometimes?

Comment: You should have included the choices in your statement of the question!  That changes everything.  All transitions can emit a photon, so all are correct.   Yes, they can emit two, but taking that interpretation is overthinking the problem.  And despite the reputation of the IITJEE,  I think the question could be phrased better.

Comment: Oh, really? How does that change everything? They specified just "one quantum of energy" so I was confused because it is possible for them to emit more than one in 3 out of 4 of those transitions. Yes, I also agree that it could definitely be phrased *better*. The question isn't wrong was the point I was trying to make when I said all that about the IITJEE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments, I note that the following additional information applies :

> The options are as follows:
>   $a. 4\to 2$
>   $b. 2\to 1$
>   $c. 3\to 1$
>   $d. 4\to 1$
>   And according to the answer key, all the options are correct!

I presume these numbers relate to the principal quantum number $n$ which identifies the energy levels of an isolated hydrogen atom. There are additional subordinate quantum numbers for each value of $n$. As @lemon points out, **selection rules** restrict which transitions can result in the absorption or emission of a photon. However, such transitions are always possible between any 2 states with a different principal quantum number $n$.

So for each option the transition *can* result in the emission of a single photon. At your level of study, absorption or emission *will* occur only 1 photon at a time, and you are correct in making this assumption. So as you note from the answer, all options are correct.

Perhaps where you are getting confused is that 2 or more *consecutive* transitions are also possible, with some delay in between : eg $4\to 3\to 2\to 1$ with the emission of 3 photons, each with different energies.

The largest release of energy is usually the most likely - provided that other quantum numbers can change according to the selection rules. So for a hydrogen atom excited to the $n=4$ level the transition $4\to 1$ is most likely, with the emission of a single photon. But nothing prevents the transitions $4\to 2$ or $4\to 3$ instead, with later transitions $2\to 1$ or $3\to 1$ or $3\to 2\to 1$ eventually leading down to the $n=1$ level, with the emission of more photons - again 1 for each transition. These are much less likely but not impossible, and represent a small proportion of the transitions which do occur.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware of the fact that the other transitions are much less likely. Thanks for clearing this up; I'll keep this in mind :)